# Solr 6: how to group by title and return groups that contain minimum 5 numFound

Tags: solr

I want to group results by title which beginning with some letter:

```
&group=true
&group.field=title
&fq=title:A*
....
```

But, need only results that contain minimum 5 numFound.

How to query / filter in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is [no direct way](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Get-groups-which-has-the-number-of-elements-greater-than-td4174352.html) to do that in `group` query.
But you can do that by using `facet.pivot` like:
Note: Use only if you just need count not whole document.

```
...
&facet=true
&facet.pivot=title
&facet.pivot.mincount=5
...
```

But If you need Document while grouping then you need query two time.

1. The first one to get [facet](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html) (where you get some `title`s which count grater then `5`), eg.:

   ```
   ...
   &facet.field=title
   &facet=on
   &facet.mincount=5
   ...
   ```

   This query result is multiple value of of title which match with `5` same value in collection like:

   ```
   11015 437027 412601
   ```
2. Then a second one for [group](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/result-grouping.html):

   ```
   ...
   &group=true
   &group.field=title
   &fq=title:(11015 437027 412601)
   ...
   ```

   It will give you a desired Result.

Comment: @Salines As of my knowledge it is wrong syntax you need to put `:` separator between field and value or values here it is values separated by space and if it is string containing space it self the you need to put one vale in double quote.

Comment: i have typo in comments, fq=title:(111 OR 222)