# SOLR sort by grouping num found

Tags: search, indexing, solr, grouping, solrcloud

Hello **StackOverflow**,

Environments: Solr 7.5.0|SolrCloud 7.5.0, Custom search index.

According to requirements for search, it should group search response by specific field and sort groups by **score** and by **numFound** group value then
[image: Solr Grouping Picture]

I saw some links that noticed that it is not possible or it is possible through two queries using facets (implemented currently). But they are pretty old and probably something changed.

For example:

1. [how to order groups by count in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457868/how-to-order-groups-by-count-in-solr)
2. [Solr 6: how to group by title and return groups that contain minimum 5 numFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219765/solr-6-how-to-group-by-title-and-return-groups-that-contain-minimum-5-numfound)
3. [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9678?jql=text%20~%20%22numFound%22](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9678?jql=text%20%7E%20%22numFound%22)

Also, heard that this purpose can be reached through SOLR subqueries. But also no luck to find a solution for this.

Will appreciate any help.